# Refactoring else-if operators with different extensions?

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I want to know how we better way refctoring this part of code with else-if operators. When is performed eguals check with different extentions?

**Code:**

```
    private void findFiles(String path) {

        try {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".pdf"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".doc"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".docx"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".html"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".htm"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".xml"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".djvu"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".djv"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".rar"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } else if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith((".rtf"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    } 
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Questions:**

- How better way to refactoring code? Make it simpler for
  understanding.
- Can we use some another way to check `extentions`
  variants?

Thanks,
Nazar.

Comment: You should probably "cache" `currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()`, at least.

Comment: is that copy&paste or the code does the same action with every matched extension?

Comment: Or get the last index of `"."` and compare the substring (extension)?

Comment: One, you're being terribly inefficient by calling `currentFile.getName().toLowerCase()` over and over. That results in 3 method calls every time and makes the code hard to understand. You only need to do that once.

Comment: If you extract the extension you don't have such a hard time comparing it.
Since Java 7 you then have the ability to use a switch/case-construct to compare the extension - if you need to distinguish the extensions. Otherwise you might create a List/an Array of the valid extensions and check, if the list contains the extracted extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
String s = currentFile.getName().toLowerCase();
if (s.matches("^.+?\\.(txt|pdf|doc|docx|html|htm|xml|djvu|rar|rtf)$")) {
    queue.put(currentFile);
}
```

That assumes that the action to be taken is the same for all extensions.

In details:

```
^         beginning of string
.+        one or more characters
?         non greedy -> don't consume characters that match the rest of the regex
\\.       a period
(pdf|doc) match pdf or doc
$         the end of the string
```

Comment: +1 for me, you may want to flag for case insensitive match.

Comment: @guido the string is in lower case already so it should be fine (unless I misunderstand your comment).

Comment: I meant to not call toLowerCase() and match case insensitive; in general it means worse execution time but you might want to capture the file name or part of it, without loosing case in the same match. anyway I was going offtopic probably.

Comment: @assylias `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable` - warnings

Comment: @nazar_art On what line? I don't get that warning so it is probably due to some other code (maybe you already use `s` somewhere else).

Comment: @assylias All work perfect, it was my mistake.

Comment: @assylias Can you recoment some good tutorial about `regex`?

Comment: @nazar_art A good start is the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Comment: @nazar_art In particular this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Answer (score 8):

You can replace your whole list of checking extensions with this:

```
// outside the loop (or even method):
Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(".txt", ".pdf", ".doc",
                 ".docx", ".html", ".htm", ".xml", ".djvu", ".rar", ".rtf"));
// in the loop:
String fileName = currentFile.getName().toLowerCase();
if (extensions.contains(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")))) {
    queue.put(currentFile);
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling he doesn't really want to do the same action in every case, otherwise that code would be dumb. That's probably just for show.

Comment: good but you need to extract the extension from the filename

Comment: Same idea as mine. I would use a HashSet instead of a List, though. O(1) rather than O(n).

Comment: @guido: Yes, you are right, forgot about that ;) Edited my answer...

Comment: @JBNizet How do you think of the current answer? Creating a `HashSet` from a `List` doesn't seem quite efficient either.

Comment: @AlvinWong Considering there are 10 items in the list, we are talking about milliseconds (if not less), that will be executed once in the whole program.

Comment: @assylias and we should remind the OP to put that **outside** the for-loop.

Comment: @AlvinWong Of course. It should not even be in the method. More like a `private static final` member for example.

Comment: @jlordo Need add <String> => `... new HashSet<String>(...)`

Comment: @nazar_art: Edited, used the Java 7 diamond operator, though.

Comment: @jlordo don't find correctly?

Comment: @nazar_art: Either way is correct. I am lazy and therefor prefer the diamond operator.

Comment: this won't still work for `.tar.gz`

Comment: @guido: then you have to add `".gz"` to the list... (or use an `else if`)... Or something else...

Comment: what if you want to accept `.tar.gz` but not `.man.gz`

Comment: @guido: I'm sure you'll find a solution if you encounter that problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to refactor this to the STRATEGY Pattern, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529856/modifying-if-else-to-strategy-pattern):

Comment: You don't have to throw design patterns at every problem. Especially since the solution that jlordo proposed is both, elegant and short enough to solve the problem.

Comment: agree in case he has different logic for each case

Comment: Clearly if he really is trying to do the same logic in every block, a pattern is overkill. I was going for the more general "what's a succinct way of refactoring away if-else chains" type of question, which seemed to be what was implied.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a getExtension() method, which returns the extension of the file, and a final set of accepted extensions:

```
private static final Set<String> ACCEPTED_EXTENSIONS = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(".txt", ".doc", ...));

private String getExtension(File f) {
    // TODO return the extension of the file
}
```

The code would then be redueced to:

```
private void findFiles(String path) {

    try {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        for (File currentFile : list) {
            if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } 
            else if (ACCEPTED_EXTENSIONS.contains(getExtension(currentFile))) {
                queue.put(currentFile);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or even better, I would create a FileFilter which only accepts directories and files with one of the accepted extensions (using the same set and `getExtension()` method), and would use `root.listFiles(fileFilter)`.

Comment: I understand, but getExtension() could be tricky for something like `.tar.gz`

Comment: how better return extention from `private String getExtension(File f) {  }`

Comment: Find the first dot in the String, and return everything from this index to the end of the String. Without caring about file without an extension, it's as simple as `file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf('.')).toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a method**

```
public boolean isPermissibleFileType(String fileName){
    String[] fileTypes = {".pdf",".doc",".docx",".html",".htm",".xml",".djvu",".djv",".rar",".rtf"};
    return Arrays.asList(fileTypes).contains(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase());
}
```

**Use Method in Loop**

```
private void findFiles(String path) {

        try {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    if(isPermissibleFileType(currentFile.getName()){
                       queue.put(currentFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to extract the extensions from currentFile

Comment: @guido Good catch. I updated.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox A little bit long run but work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the extension checks into some helper method using class [FileNameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html). And then for recursion you can use your original finder method.