# Design pattern for handling app configuration

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a configuration file in following format :

```
item1=true
value=test
item2=false
```

pseudocode in app logic :

```
if(item1)
{
   do something
}
else {
   do something else
}

if(item2)
{
   do something
}
else {
   do something else
}
```

Is there pattern to handle this kind of configuration ? So instead of conditional statements use something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect time to use the strategy pattern, you might want to follow [the answer from this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529856/modifying-if-else-to-strategy-pattern) but you'd execute a specific strategy based on the boolean

[This](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Replace_conditional_logic_with_strategy_pattern) is an excellent write up example from the guys at IntelliJ entitled

> Replace conditional logic with strategy pattern

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific needs, maybe you'll consider using "Feature Toggle": http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html or http://www.togglz.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are several patterns you might use, I might use an [Interpreter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern),

[image: Interpreter Pattern]

or a [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

[image: Command Pattern]

or a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

[image: Stategy Pattern]

Answer (score 1):

You can use command pattern. First you can create command per option found in configuration file. Factory pattern is the best to do this. Tour factory can create a collection of commands. Then run these commands in loop.

The factory can be implemented using `enum`:

```
public enum CommmandFactory {
    item1 {
         @Override
         public ConfCommand create(String value) {
             return new ItemOneCmd(value);
         }
    },
    item2 {
         @Override
         public ConfCommand create(String value) {
             return new ItemTwoCmd(value);
         }
    },


    public abstract ConfCommand create(String value);
}
```

Now use the this factory as following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(yourInuptStream);
for (Entry<Object, Object> e : props.entrySet()) {
   CommmandFactory.valueOf((String)e.getKey()).create((String)e.getValue()).execute();
}
```